# How to ask bash to wait for a result and send a SIGKILL when it get it?

Tags: bash, keyboard, stdout, barcode, sigint

I want to use zbarcam but after reading a barcode, it doesn't stop.

```
$ zbarcam | xvkbd -file - -window emacs
EAN-13:6941428130969
CODE-128:3096140900557
```

Do you know how I can tell bash to kill zbarcam after printing on the stdout the first \n ?

Comment: +1 for making me aware of zbarcam, that looks cool!

Comment: Yes, it is really cool. http://zbar.sf.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
tmp=/tmp/barcode.$$ # Note: security risk
zbarcam > $tmp &
pid=$!
# Sleep until file has content
while [[ ! -s $tmp ]] ; do
    sleep 1
done
kill $pid
cat $tmp
```

Note that it might not work if zbarcam doesn't flush its output.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
zbarcam | head -1 | xvkbd -file - -window emacs
```

Comment: It just stop to write on the virtual keyboard but doesn't stop zbarcam.

Comment: Ok, the technique works for some things, but not everything.  Glad you got another answer that worked for you.

Answer (score -1):

```
tmp=/tmp/barcode.$$ # Note: security risk
zbarcam > $tmp &
pid=$!
# Sleep until file has content
while [[ ! -s $tmp ]] ; do
    sleep 1
done
kill $pid
cat $tmp
```